# excel replacement values for N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row having some values from `A1` to `A3`. I have

```
1
3
#N/A
```

I tried

```
=SUM(A1:A3)
```

But since I have value as #N/A am not able get the sum of 3 values. I want to treat #N/A as 0 and get the sum

Comment: Perhaps you might use the IFERROR() function to convert the N/A error to zero at source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) function is great for ignoring error terms

```
=AGGREGATE(9,6,A1:A3)
```

---

Check the link I provided for more info but specific to the formula above:

- `9` represents the `SUM` formula
- `6` means ignore error terms (treat as equal to zero)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not aware of Aggregate function, you will need to use **Array Formulas** which can handle this kind of data easily.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(A1:A3,0))
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A3),A1:A3))
```

Both the formulas above will require a special key stroke **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**